# Migrate Flutter project to AndroidX

Tags: android, flutter, dart, androidx

The issue I was facing was to build and run my application and terminal saying 'Your project is doesn't support AndroidX'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration

So I went to the given link and tried to implement it by the help of Android Studio, but it always leads to `No usage found.`

So I went back to the link and tried the other approach of editing the `gradle.properties` in `android` level (`android/gradle`) and add these properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```